# receive two word input in batch not working

Tags: batch-file

I have very little training in batch, but i am trying to make a game like zork. if you don't know what that is, it is a text based game that requires the player to type what they would like their actions to be. I am trying to get the player to say a two word command, but it just closes. 
here is where it happens:

```
    set /p %input%=
if %input%==go left goto left2
```

basically i type in go left and the screen flickers a message saying something about right=menu is unexpected or something. it disappears too fast. Is more code needed? When you input your name at the start, it can be 50 words long if you want. This is probably a terrible question but i need help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the `%` from your variable name, and then quote both sides for the comparison:

```
set /p input=
if "%input%"=="go left" goto left2
```

Test batch file (saved as `input_test.bat`):

```
set /p input=
if "%input%"=="go left" goto left2
```

Sample run and output:

[image: Batch file output image]

Comment: Um, yes. It does. I tested it on my own system before posting it; I just changed the `goto` to an `echo` instead. If it's not working for you, you have something else wrong. (I've posted a working test batch file and graphic of the results of that test file.)

Comment: i figured out the problem. it was calling on the input i had used in the class that came before that one. thanks for the assistance though ^-^